How to make this template specialization for ending recursion work on a conforming compiler?
I have the following minimal example:
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <int D>
struct B
{
    template <class T>
    static void Check(const std::vector<std::vector<T> >& value, size_t size1 = 0, std::string nameType1 = "", size_t size2 = 0, std::string nameType2 = "")
    {
        //BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(D > 1); // specialized for D == 1
        B<1>::Check(value, size1, nameType1, size2, nameType2);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
            B<D - 1>::Check(value[i], size2, nameType2);
        }
    }
};

template <>
struct B<1>
{
    template <class T>
    static void Check(const std::vector<T>& value, size_t size1 = 0, std::string nameType1 = "", size_t size2 = 0, std::string nameType2 = "")
    {
        if (value.size() != size1) {
            // Throw with error message
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m;
    B<2>::Check<int>(m, 4, "test1", 3, "test2");
}

In the real code, there are more arguments to the 'Check' function, like type3, nameType3, type4 etc. The goal of this is to have a generic way to check the size of each element of a nested vector. The way this (used to) work(s) is by having the Check() call from main() calling the non-specialized version, doing the check on one 'dimension' of the vector, then 'stripping off' one vector, recursively calling itself until it gets to the specialization for <1> at which point the recursion stops.
Now this is quite old code and this used to work with MSVC in non-conforming/non-strict mode (/permissive). Now I'm porting everything to C++20/non-permissive and this fails to compile with the error message:
Test.cpp(19,8): error C2908: explicit specialization; 'B<1>' has already been instantiated
Test.cpp(19,8): error C2766: explicit specialization; 'B<1>' has already been defined

Poking around on godbolt shows that there are different error being thrown by different compilers depending on version and strictness settings.
My question is - is there a way to do this in a standard-compliant way? If not, what sort of alternative approach could I take? (short from having a bunch of overloads for each 'depth' of vector nesting, which I could still automate with boost_pp, but ideally I'm looking for a way that doesn't involve the pre-processor).
Edit re: closing: well I guess the referenced question is at first glance 'identical' in a very loose meaning of that word, i.e. in the sense that they're both about using a specialized template from its non-specialized form, but I would never in a million years have found the linked question with the information and symptoms I was working with, nor would I probably have spend the time to understand the linked question well enough to reduce my fundamental problem to the solution in there. So any future person searching for this topic from the same angle I came to it, will now not find this answer. Look, my specific problem is solved so I don't really care if it's re-opened, but this is to me yet again a typical SO experience example of overzealous moderation for no benefit at all to anyone by someone who probably only has a superficial understanding of both questions in the first place (although I can't see who closed it, so if it was the person who provided the accepted answer, apologies and thanks again :) )

if constexpr (C++17) might be an alternative to specialization; that might also resolve your issue.

You need to define B<1> before using it.
template <int D>
struct B {
    // only declare the primary class template's Check here:
    template <class T>
    static void Check(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& value,
                      size_t size1 = 0, std::string nameType1 = "",
                      size_t size2 = 0, std::string nameType2 = "");
};

template <>
struct B<1> {
    template <class T>
    static void Check(const std::vector<T>& value, size_t size1 = 0,
                      std::string nameType1 = "", size_t size2 = 0,
                      std::string nameType2 = "") {
        if (value.size() != size1) {
            // Throw with error message
        }
    }
};

// ... and define it after B<1> is defined:
template <int D>
template <class T>
void B<D>::Check(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& value, size_t size1,
                 std::string nameType1, size_t size2, std::string nameType2) {
    B<1>::Check(value, size1, nameType1, size2, nameType2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
        B<D - 1>::Check(value[i], size2, nameType2);
    }
}

Demo

This looked completely unintuitive at first glance yet was completely obvious once I read the comments :) Thanks.

@Roel You're welcome! I'm glad it helped!
